# MySQL - Show result of count

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I just trying to show a result of a consult in MySQL (PHP).
The code is:

```
$example = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as text FROM table WHERE name = '$name'");
$qtd = mysql_num_rows($example);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qtd)){
$count = $data["text"];
}

echo "<h3>($count)</h3>";
```

> Error: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\Site\index.php on line 9

Comment: You should use PDO or something, instead of `mysql_`. That set of extensions is deprecated! Also, `text` is a type; try using a different name or putting it in backticks.

Comment: Your query fails. Debug it with `mysql_error`.

Comment: why are you SELECTING COUNT and running mysql_num_rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGE THIS

```
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qtd)){
 $count = $data["text"];
 }
```

to

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($example)){
 $count = $data["text"];
  }
```

**EDIT :**
you dont need to do a while loop here.

you should just do like that

```
     $example = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as text FROM table WHERE name = '$name'");
     $data = mysql_fetch_array($example) ;
     $count = $data["text"];
     echo "<h3>".$count."</h3>";
```

Comment: This is a good advice, but it does not address the provided error message. The query failed in the first place.

Comment: yes it comes because u tried to fetch mysql_num_rows and its wrong

Comment: `$qtd = mysql_num_rows($example);` is not useful.  Your query has a one-row resultset, which contains the count.   That same line is also incorrect; you can't count the rows of a SQL statement, but rather of the rewsultset generated by the statement.

Comment: when he fetched the mysql_num_rows it throws the error in that line , so fix your error by my solution

Comment: `$qtd = mysql_num_rows($example);` as Ollie said is not usefull here

Comment: From error message it is clear that `$example` is `false`. The query failed. Any function applied to `$example` will fail.

Comment: his query is good only if `$name` is wrong because he didnt show that variable. else the erros comes from when he fetched

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you don't need to use a while statement.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$name'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $count;
```